# Using `defined?` at one-level expansion

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

The method `defined?` gives the result for the verbatim expression given as an argument. For example, the result of

```
defined? foo
```

is sensitive to whether `foo` is literally any defined variable/method. It does not make difference whether `foo` is defined as a string that is a valid (existing) expression:

```
foo = "Array"
```

or not:

```
foo = "NonExistingConstant"
```

Is it possible to make `defined?` be sensitive to the given argument expanded one level? That is, for `foo = "Array"`, it should return `"constant"` and for `foo = "NonExistingConstant"`, it should return `nil`. If so, how?

Comment: Are you going to check only constants? `const_get` then, maybe?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes. Your guess is right. I am actually using `const_get`, but wanted to condition it so that it is evaluated only when there is such constant. I am using `rescue` now, but wanted to do it without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to check only constants:

```
['Array', 'NonExistentClass'].each do |name|
  puts Object.const_defined?(name)
end
# >> true
# >> false
```

Comment: My problem is solved, but just for curiousity: Since there is `const_defined?`, I suppose there is no general one like `expression_defined?`. I wonder why the verbatim one `defined?` is for general purpose and the ones that take a string like `const_defined?` (and other similar ones) are more specific.

Comment: Okay. I seem I have the answer to my comment above. It pairs with the methods that evaluate them. Since there is the general `eval`/`exec`, the general `defined?` would be useful. And since there are specific methods like `const_get`, specific checking methods like `const_defined?` are useful. Or, I don't know. Maybe this might not make sense.

Comment: I personally use `defined?` only for method existence checks. And even in those cases it can be replaced with `respond_to?`. I don't see much need for a general `expression_defined?` method/operator.